# objective C sort 2D array on multiple columns?

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I have an array of data like so.

```
{
"first_name"="John",
"last_name"="Lock"
};
{
"first_name"="John",
"last_name"="Lee"
};
{
"first_name"="Melinda",
"last_name"="Abman"
};
```

I was able to sort by first name like so:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [tablearray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"first_name" ascending:YES]]];
```

But is there a simple way to sort by firstname then lastname?  Basically do the equivalent of `SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY first_name ASC, last_name ASC` ?

Comment: Manually you can sort, rebuild your Model(array), and show it in View(NSTableView). Same thing I did. Also, Thanks for posting this question if any better solution we can get :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCJGCJI) takes an array of `NSSortDescriptor`'s so you can simply keep adding sortDescripters.

```
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[
  [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"first_name" ascending:YES],
  [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"last_name" ascending:YES]
];

NSLog(@"%@", [array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors]);
```